# Setting upload_max_filesize with .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload

I want to set the upload_max_filesize to 3G (or max) with my .htaccess because I have no access to php.ini. I have done a lot of research and this is what I've got now:

---

.htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 3G
php_value post_max_size 3G
php_value memory_limit 3G
php_value post_max_size 3G
php_value upload_max_filesize 3G
```

but somehow this is not working for me. When I add

```
echo "Max file upload size: " . ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
```

to my PHP script I only get this response:

```
Max file upload size: 4M
```

When I use `php5_value` instead of `php_value` I get a 500 internal server error

So what am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit/Solution:**
I'm using a shared hosting service which doesn't allow me to modify values in php.ini. That's why settings `php_value` didn't work/threw an error.

Comment: Have You tried to set size in megabytes (M) ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to the php.ini file because I'm using a shared host. Thanks for your time and comment anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously don’t have access on shared hosting to do that and php5_x is probably invalid because it’s php 7.x version on server. Try contacting support and ask them to increase the limit for you. If that doesn’t work, change your hosting to some kind of VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: Thank you, you were right I don't have access on my shared host!